# What can I use to determine similar words or keywords?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Does anyone know of a "similar words or keywords" algorithm available in open source or via an API?  I am looking for something sort of like a thesaurus but smarter.

So for example:

> intel

returns:

> processor,
> i7 core chip,
> quad core chip,
> .. etc

Any ideas or even something to point me in the right direction in C#?

---

#### Edit:

I would love to hear your thoughts, but why cant we just use the Google Adwords API to generate keywords relevant to those entered?

Comment: Any such "thesaurus" would be highly specialized, since the general population would probably correspond "intel" to "knowledge, intelligence, wisdom, learning, spy, espionage", etc...

Comment: yep - think the search engines will have to solve this problem. on further inspection - google adwords API offers a solution ... but its $0.25 for per 1K of calls - requesting a keyword returns 20 similar results .... so its 0.005 per 20 similar words .... not really viable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not send a search query out to Google and parse what it returns?

Also, check out [Google Sets](http://labs.google.com/sets).

Comment: yeah this is cool - but no accessible API :(
not sure whether it possible to use the google adwords API to access keywords aka - https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal - this technology.

or even something like "google suggest" and parse results ?

Comment: @Andy: Sometimes you do not have an API available and you need to do your own screen scraping. This might be one of those times.

Comment: @Rich - agreed. seems htmlagilitypack will do the job nicely. thinking the MS link seems to be pretty sweet. thx for the help

Answer (score 2):

There is no algorithm for such a thing.  You are going to have to acquire data for a Thesaurus, and load it into a data structure then it is a simple dictionary lookup (you can use the C# Dictionary class for that).  Maybe you can look at [Wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/obtain), or [Moby Thesaurus](http://www.gutenberg.org/etext/3202) as a source for data.  Other options are using a [Thesaurus server](http://www.alexandria.ucsb.edu/thesaurus/) and getting the information online as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a large database containing this information. The rest is simple - look up the input and see what releated words are stored.

The hard part is generating the database. Doing it manually might take years if you want to cover a large number of words and topics.
Generating it is surly non-trivial. Maybe you could try to download web pages and analyze words frequently appearing together, but I assume this will still take months to build, tune, and finally gather good quality data. Maybe extracting links from Wikipedia might be a good source of information because of its semi-structure.

Answer (score 0):

I've made the open office thesaurus functions available for .NET in the NHunspell project. You can use the OO Thesaurus files. 
[Here is the NHunspell Project](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/)